# ¿Cómo solucionaría este problema en colision?

Tags: c++

Tengo problemas al compilar colision y cumple su deber pero despues de presionar otro disparo me bota error:

> (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'Un componente externo produjo una excepción.')

```
bool Controladora::colision()
{
    bool resultado_colision = false;


    for (int i = 0; i < !resultado_colision && i < objNave->retornar_cant_balas(); i++)
    {
        
        Rectangle r2 = arreglo.at(i)->retornar_rectangle();
        Rectangle r3 = objNave->retornar_bala_enpos(i)->retornar_rectangle();

            if (r2.IntersectsWith(r3))
            {
                resultado_colision = true;
                arreglo.at(i)->cambiar_eliminar(resultado_colision);
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arreglo.at(i)->retornar_eliminar())
        {
            arreglo.erase(arreglo.begin() + i);
            objNave->retornar_bala_enpos(i)->cambiar_eliminar(resultado_colision);
        }
    }
    
    
    return resultado_colision;
}
```

Comment: `i < !resultado_colision` Que se supone que haga esto? Pasando de ello, el unico metodo que me consta que tira excepciones entre los que tienes ahi es `at` (suponiendo que `arreglo` es un `std::array` o un `std::vector`). Supongo que en el primer loop tratas de acceder a elementos que no existen en `arreglo`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está sucediendo ahí es que .Net está tratando de cerrar una asa de una ventana (window handle) usando la función CloseHandle() y la función está fallando.  Normalmente CloseHandle() falla cuando la asa es inválida, probablemente porque ya se había cerrado con anterioridad.

No se puede ver que hacen las funciones `cambiar_eliminar(resultado_colision)` y `retornar_eliminar()` pero pondría la mano en el fuego que estás tratando de eliminar el mismo elemento una vez cada ciclo.

Si necesites més ajuda no dubtis en preguntar